# Nested forms not saving information in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have user and profile model. I created a form for user and profile. when anyone enters the detail, only the details of user gets saved in database and not of profile.

User model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord  has_many :comments

  has_many :repositories
  has_many :searches
  has_many :issues
  has_many :feedbacks
  has_one :profile
#-------------------------- VALIDATIONS-----------------------------------------#
  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
  validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :password, :confirmation => true #password_confirmation attr
  validates_length_of :password, :in => 6..20, :on => :create
#-------------------------- ENCRYPTION-----------------------------------------#

  before_save :encrypt_password, :default_values
  after_save :clear_password

  def encrypt_password
    if password.present?
      self.salt = BCrypt::Engine.generate_salt
      self.encrypted_password= BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
    end
  end

  def clear_password
    self.password = nil
  end
#-------------------------- AUTHENTICATION-----------------------------------------#
  def self.authenticate(username_or_email="", login_password="")
    if  EMAIL_REGEX.match(username_or_email)
      user = User.find_by_email(username_or_email)
    else
      user = User.find_by_username(username_or_email)
    end
    if user && user.match_password(login_password)
      return user
    else
      return false
    end
  end

def match_password(login_password="")
  encrypted_password == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(login_password, salt)
end

private
def default_values
  type ||= false
end

end
```

Profile model

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord

  before_save :default_values
  belongs_to :user


  validates :fname, :presence=> true
  validates :lname, :presence=> true
  validates :city,  :presence=> true
  validates :state, :presence=> true
  validates :country,  :presence=> true
  validates :zip_code, :presence=> true
  validates :phone_no, :presence=> true

  private
  def default_values
    followers ||= 0
    following ||= 0
  end
end
```

User controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :save_login_state, :only => [:new, :create]

  def new
    @user = User.new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @profile = Profile.new(profile_params)
    if @user.save
          @profile.save
          flash.now[:notice] = "Signed up successfully !!"
          @users = User.all                               # to get all users in @users
          @profiles = Profile.all                         # to get profile of all users in @profiles
          render "show"                                    # display show.html.erb while passing @users and @profiles ?
        else
          flash.now[:notice] = "Invalid form"
          flash.now[:color] = "Invalid"
          redirect_to :root

      end
  end

def show
  @users = User.all                     # same as above. not working if removed from above.
  @profiles = Profile.all               # same as above. not working if removed from above.
end

def edit
  user = @current_user               
  profile = user.profile               
end

private
def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password)
end

def profile_params
  params.require(:profile).permit(:fname, :lname, :dob, :city, :state, :country, :zip_code ,:phone_no)
end

end
```

Signup page - new.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="signup.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<!--webfonts-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--//webfonts-->
</head>
<body id="signup_body">
    <ul id="navigation">
    <li><%= link_to "Home", {:action=>'index', :controller=>'home'}, class: "home_list"%></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Personal", {:action=> 'login', :controller=>'sessions'}, class: "home_list"%></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Business", {:action=>'business', :controller=> 'home'}, class: "home_list" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Pricing", {:action=>'pricing', :controller=>'home'}, class: "home_list" %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "Signup", {:action=>'new', :controller=>'users'}, class: "home_list" %></li>
   </ul>
<div class="main">
    <div class="social-icons">
         <div class="col_1_of_f span_1_of_f">
         </div>
         <div class="col_1_of_f span_1_of_f">
        </div>
        <div class="clear"> </div>
      </div>
      <h2>Signup</h2>
           <div class="lable">
         <%= form_for @user, :as => :user, url:{action: :"create"} do |f| %>
           <div class="col_1_of_2 span_1_of_2"><%= f.text_field :username, :class => 'text', :value=>'Username', :onfocus=>"this.value = '';" %></div>
           <div class="col_1_of_2 span_1_of_2"><%= f.text_field :email, :class => 'text', :value=>'Email', :onfocus=>"this.value = '';" %></div>
           <div class="col_1_of_2 span_1_of_2"><%= f.password_field :password, :class => 'text', :value=>'Password', :onfocus=>"this.value = '';" %></div>
            <div class="col_1_of_2 span_1_of_2"><%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, :class => 'text', :value=>'Password', :onfocus=>"this.value = '';" %></div>
                <div class="clear"> </div>
           </div>
           <div class="lable-2">
         <%= fields_for :profile, :as => :profile, url:{action: :"create"} do |t| %>
          <b><u>Profile</b></u>
            <%= t.text_field :fname, :class => 'text', :value=>'First Name', :onfocus=>"this.value = '';" %>
                <%= t.text_field :lname, :class => 'text', :value=>'Last Name', :onfocus=>"this.value = '';" %>
            <%= t.text_field :dob, :class => 'text', :value=>'Date of birth (yyyy/mm/dd)', :onfocus=>"this.value = '';" %>
                        <%= t.text_field :city, :class => 'text', :value=>'City', :onfocus=>"this.value = '';" %>
                        <%= t.text_field :state, :class => 'text', :value=>'State', :onfocus=>"this.value = '';" %>
                        <%= t.text_field :country, :class => 'text', :value=>'Country', :onfocus=>"this.value = '';" %>
                        <%= t.text_field :zip_code, :class => 'text', :value=>'Zip Code', :onfocus=>"this.value = '';" %>
                        <%= t.text_field :phone_no, :class => 'text', :value=>'Phone Number', :onfocus=>"this.value = '';" %>
           </div>
           <h3>By creating an account, you agree to our <span> class="term">Terms & Conditions</span></h3>
             <br>
             <%= flash[:message] %>
           <div class="submit">
              <%= f.submit(:Submit, :value=> 'Create Account' , :style=> 'margin-left:5px;float:left;margin-top:55px;height:50px;width:520px;padding:10px;border-radius:4px;') %>
           </div>
           <div class="clear"> </div>
        </form><br><br>
        <!--//end-main---->
        </div>
</body>
<%end%>
<% end %>
</html>
```

Console

```
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" = ? LIMIT ?  [["username", "qwerty"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = ? LIMIT ?  [["email", "qwerty@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("username", "password", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "salt", "encrypted_password") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["username", "qwerty"], ["password", "1234567"], ["email", "qwerty@gmail.com"], ["created_at", 2017-04-23 06:44:39 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-04-23 06:44:39 UTC], ["salt", "$2a$10$bZSiXCku1iYArTRpo4ExAO"], ["encrypted_password", "$2a$10$bZSiXCku1iYArTRpo4ExAOXYGjLVKN.PJCMOUdoat0CrYIY/zUGM."]]
(2.0ms)  commit transaction
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendering users/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
  Profile Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles"
  Rendered users/show.html.erb within layouts/application (4.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 144ms (Views: 37.0ms | ActiveRecord: 4.3ms)
```

P.S : I am new to rails.

Comment: are u sure that you have connection between `user` and `profile`? Instead of `@profile = Profile.new(profile_params)` It's better to create profile like this: `@profile = user.build_profile` and pass params there.

Comment: u mean @profile=user.build_profile(profile_params) ?

Comment: yes, try this out.

Comment: it says : undefined local variable or method `user' for #<UsersController:0x007f9c0c71c2a8>

Comment: you should use `@user` instead of `user`, I made typo, sorry.

Comment: thanks it worked ! but how do i show the values in view ? for profile.
i previously wrote

Comment: <% @user.profile.each do |profile| %>

Comment: It's another question and offtopic for this one. Please take a look at Rails associations -http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html Since you have single profile, you should just use `@profile.attribute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something more simple, on the user model add this line

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

with this then if the params have the correct structure, when you create the user, the profile will be added too. just remember to add the parameters on the permit in the controller as

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :email, :password,
  profile_attributes: [:id, :attribute1, :attribute2])
end

and on your create action, you just add this

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save              
          flash.now[:notice] = "Signed up successfully !!"
          @users = User.all
          @profiles = Profile.all    
          render "show"   
        else
          flash.now[:notice] = "Invalid form"
          flash.now[:color] = "Invalid"
          redirect_to :root

      end
  end
```

in this way, the user and the profile will be created and if there is an error in any of them, with the validations, none will be saved, and you don't have to worry about deleting the user if the profile wasn't saved.